# How to display a CCTV rtsp stream in a grails web page

Tags: tomcat, grails, video-streaming, vlc, rtsp

I have a web server (Apache Tomcat) running on a raspberry Pi (Raspian).

I have a Grails web service running on Tomcat, and I'd like to create a page that displays an embedded video stream (rtsp) from my IP cctv camera.

Running around in circles wondering what the easiest way to do this is?  Some signposts would be really appreciated. And if there is a tutorial out there, even better.

I'm not hugely experienced in any of the technologies I'm playing with!  But I can manage to put Grails apps together. (Just).

Grails 2.5.6 OpenJDK 1.8 Tomcat 8

Comment: "Some signposts would be really appreciated." - Stackoverflow is quite likely to close the question because it is too general.  If you have a specific question, that would be a better fit.  We have a community Slack channel at https://slack.grails.org/ which is a great place to discuss ideas.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, that's much appreciated. See you on Slack!